# Socket Connection doesn't work on WatchOS 9

Tags: swift, watchos

I noticed that socket connections doesn't work on real devices on watchOS 9.

It was working well on WatchOS 8 & WatchOS 7.

Is this a bug or a new restriction for WatchOS 9 ?

**Similar issues:**

- [Cannot connect to server on watchOS 9](https://github.com/pusher/NWWebSocket/issues/35)
- [WebSocket connect failed in WatchOS9](https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream/issues/957)
- [Database socket calls do not work on watchOS 9](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/10195)

Comment: Please provide more information about your issue.
What "doesn't work" on a real device? How is it?

Comment: @Neklas Connection is not established. How can I make it clear more?

Comment: @Neklas there really isn’t any more context to give. Websocket code  that worked fine on watchOS 8 doesn’t work at all on watchOS 9.

Comment: I'm not sure how it could have been phrased any better but I'm seeing the exact same issue too. In the past, some socket code hasn't worked on watchOS but like you describe, I have had code that has worked across a number of watchOS releases that now no longer works.

Comment: Having the same issue. Can't believe they would break, or remove this functionality. I can't imagine how many apps just stopped working with Watch OS 9 after working in simulation for so long before the release.

Answer (score 2):

See documented Tech Note: [TN3135](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/technotes/tn3135-low-level-networking-on-watchos)

Only high-level networking is allowed for use in WatchOS, aside from a few low-level networking scenarios listed in the above Tech Note.

Low-level networking will typically always work in the simulator due to using your Mac's networking capabilities. It also sometimes worked in WatchOS 6-8 due to a bug where restrictions on low-level networking were not working properly, which has been fixed in WatchOS 9.